# Is it required to add bash cmd to dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In other words, what is the purpose of adding

```
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

in the dockerfile?

I have a dockerfile which previously had these following 2 lines

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
...

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Do I need a CMD at the end? What's the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62504550/5666087) says, you don't need it unless you want it. In your specific case, where you are using `ubuntu:16.04` as the base image, it would be redundant anyways because the [`ubuntu:16.04` Dockerfile](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/7c60863f1bdc0466b648ada069d29a49107cc7be/xenial/Dockerfile#L43) specifies `/bin/bash` as the `CMD`. Your image will inherit that, unless you set a `CMD` yourself.

Answer (score 5):

It provides a default command string to be executed by 'docker run'.

You don't need it unless you want it.